# How to check valid Date() in Swift

Tags: swift, date, nsdate

How to check if the date is valid, before making a SQL query  using

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate (format: "% @ <= AND myDate% @> = myDate" startDate, endDate)
```

an error occurs with the leap years, like 30 of February 2016.

```
// code form comment...
let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-10-01")!
let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-10-29")!
```

Comment: The 30th Feb NEVER exists. Even on a leap year Feb only goes up to 29th. As far as CoreFoundation is concerned, using the date of the 30th Feb is no different to using the date 192nd April.

Comment: let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-10-01")!
        let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-10-29")!

Comment: Sry by mistake.... The comment does get deleted from app

Comment: I found this code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605816/first-and-last-day-of-the-current-month-in-swift

Answer (score 9):

The return value of a date generated by `DateFormatter`'s `date(from:)` method is an optional. If `nil` is returned the date is invalid, otherwise it's valid.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:"2016-02-30") {
    print(date) // if this prints date is valid
}
else {
    print("Date is Invalid") // if this prints date is invalid
}
```

A `Date` cannot be instantiated with an invalid date string that is outside of the realm of real calendar dates.

If what you are asking is whether a date falls between two other dates, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40057117/1694526

Answer (score 0):

Use DateFormatter class... It can be used to check any string whether it is a valid date or not and accordingly the string can be converted into nsdata.